# Java Spring MVC - Dynamic property name of class in model

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dynamic, reflection, properties

exist easy solution how this (C# . NET):

```
    private void sortData(string param, string type)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(MusicCatalogueRowClass).GetProperty(param);
        if (type == "asc")
        {
            _Data.rows = _Data.rows.OrderBy(o => propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null)).ToList();
        }
        else {
            _Data.rows = _Data.rows.OrderByDescending(o => propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null)).ToList();
        }
        saveDataToFile();
    }
```

make in **Java Spring** (without .NET)? I wanna sort list of object by dynamic name property...

Thank you very much for any advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
   private void sortData(String param, String type)
{
    try
    {

      List<MusicCatalogueRowClass> newData= _Data.getRows();

      newData.sort(Comparator.comparing(MusicCatalogueRowClass -> {
            try {
                return (Comparable) MusicCatalogueRowClass.getClass().getDeclaredField(param).get(MusicCatalogueRowClass);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ooops", e);
            }
        })); 

      if (type.equals("desc")) {
          Collections.reverse(newData);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    saveDataToFile();
}
```